# Nested links in jQuery/html

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

This is my code:

```
            <li>
                <a href="{{ path('homepage') }}" class="active">
                    <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i> 
                    {% trans %} global.item {% endtrans %} <span id="pending-badge" class="badge pull-right">{{ pendingItems() }}</span>
                </a>
            </li>
```

And I have this jQuery too:

```
    $('#pending-badge').click(function () {
        window.location.href = '{{ path('pending') }}';
    });
```

However I've noticed clicking the badge doesn't actually redirect me to that page.

If I put `console.log('test');` in the jQuery function I do see it in the console so I know the event is being registered. But I think because it's occurring in that broader `<a>` link it's just defaulting to that (`homepage`) instead of the link I provide (`pending`) in the jQuery.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the default action by `return false` or by calling `event.preventDefault()`

```
$('#pending-badge').click(function (e) {
    window.location = 'http://google.com';
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks... out of interest if I returned "true", would that mean it would continue and allow the default action?